Why does baking normal map give back black map, only bakes one shell?
I have a model that I made in Maya I imported it to Blender as an FBX, it has UV shells, as soon as I bake the normal map in Blender, only the UVs for the neck render (they were a separate shell) here is pic of the UVs and also the bake resulting (using Cycles).
Why don't I get the rest of the mesh on the baked normals?


hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

ah I figured it out, the object or mesh had more than one material and it was just baking to the first material, if the mesh had only 1 material on it, the bake would count all the mesh, so you could duplicate your mesh then assign a single material to it.

For Blender to know which materials should be included in the baking (and which texture to bake into), it uses the selected image texture node in each material. You can have as many materials as you like, but if you need them to be baked, you need to have that same image texture node with the same image loaded inside it, and keep it selected:

You can also make all the objects use only one material, that's less work if all those materials give the exact same results. If not, you'd lose the material variety.
Addons like Textools allow to quickly bake a selection of objects without having to manually set up the baking nodes.
